# ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base 10:' '

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, integer

I got this error in Python.

I am reading from a text file, put the value in a variable and try to convert into Integer.
This is my code

```
fo = open("HCTC3152_INF.TXT", "r")
line1 = fo.readline()
```

the part in between 52:56 is the year so is always like 2013 or 2014

```
ChangeOverStartDateYYYY= int(line2[52:56],10)
print ChangeOverStartDateYYYY
```

so then, print always the years in the command prompt, and at the end appears that error.

Comment: before the `int(line...)`, do a `print line2[52:56]` to be sure that you got what you want. Maybe a line is not at the right format, or you go a shorter line…

Comment: Well, I have just did what u said, the result is:
When is print "this is from the line :" + line2[52:56]
the result is : this is from the line : 2013
and then, when I print int(line2[52:56],10), 
the result is : 2013 
but still giving me the value error! :(

Comment: HI! 
I solved. I thought about the empty lines, and because my code is in a while loop, it was taking the last line as empty, and that is the reason i gave me an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got an empty line, or a at the very least a line *shorter* than 52 characters.

Skip those lines:

```
if not line.strip():
```

to skip empty lines (consisting only of whitespace), or test for a minimal length:

```
if len(line) >= 56:
```